# Are valgrind suppression files included in the installation?

Tags: c, continuous-integration, valgrind, suppression

The `valgrind` tool's source code releases (http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html) show suppression files in the root directory, such as `darwin16.supp`.

If I want to use these files do I have to obtain them from a source download or are they added to some location on a machine during installation?

e.g. If I have my CI install `valgrind` will I then be able to reference one of these `supp` files from some location within the system or do I need to make it available in some other way?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. Note: that you don't "use" valgrind in your question.

Comment: Yes, @Stargateur, "[...] unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."  Valgrind is such a tool.  I'm nevertheless leaning toward agreeing that the question is off-topic here, but it's by no means clear.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, I not sure me too, this question look like a system administrator question for a specific OS/distrib. So I don't think this question belong to stackvoverflow.

Comment: You're probably right @Stargateur. Though I know tool-type questions are on the edge I also know that the edge is pretty blurry about this point. I searched first and saw plenty of valgrind questions so decided to post here reasoning also that programmers might have more direct knowledge than sysadmins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analysis of Valgrind's build system, particularly its top-level `Makefile.am`, shows that at build time it creates one default suppression file appropriate for the platform, and that it installs that file at the installation stage.  The default suppression file seems to be built from zero or more of the individual suppression files you're looking at, but the individual files are not installed.

What is or is not included in a particular pre-built Valgrind package is an entirely different question.  You can probably rely on the generated default suppression file to be included, as Valgrind depends on it.  For example, the Valgrind 3.12.0 packages for CentOS 7 indeed do include it.  Those particular packages *do not* include the individual component files from the Valgrind source, which is not surprising because the build system does not install them.  Other packages might nevertheless provide them.